# Is $Tr[E_i E_j] \geq 0$ for $i\neq j$ and $\{E_k\}$ a POVM?

Tags: measurement, linear-algebra, povm

Suppose that $\{E_i\}$ form a POVM (i.e. a set of positive operators satisfying $\sum_{i} E_i = I$, where $I$ denotes identity).

Is it the case that $Tr[E_i E_j] \geq 0$ for all $i \neq j$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In fact, $\mathrm{tr}(E_iE_j)\geq 0$ for all $i,j$. This follows from the following

**Lemma** If $A$ and $B$ are two positive operators on the same vector space, then $\mathrm{tr}(AB)\geq 0$.

**Proof:** Let $A=\sum_k\lambda_k|k\rangle\langle k|$ be an eigendecomposition of $A$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{tr}(AB)&=\sum_k\lambda_k\mathrm{tr}(|k\rangle\langle k|B)\tag1\\
&=\sum_k\lambda_k\langle k|B|k\rangle.\tag2
\end{align}
$$
But $A$ is positive, so $\lambda_k\ge 0$ for all $k$, and $B$ is positive, so $\langle v|B|v\rangle\ge 0$ for any $|v\rangle$. Therefore, $\mathrm{tr}(AB)\geq 0$.$\square$